# Regular expression query issue

Tags: java, regex

```
String filter = "startDate:gt(2014-07-31);(status:eq(A)||status:eq(V));endDate:gt(2014-07-31)";

String REGEX_MARKETOFFER_FILTER = "(\\(+){1}([A-Za-z]+):([A-Za-z]+)(\\(+)([a-zA-Z0-9-,:]+)(\\)+)(;|\\|\\|)([A-Za-z]+):([A-Za-z]+)(\\(+)([a-zA-Z0-9-,:]+)(\\)+)";

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_MARKETOFFER_FILTER);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(filter);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
(status:eq(A)||status:eq(V))
```

However, I was expecting this output instead:

```
startDate:gt(2014-07-31)

(status:eq(A)||status:eq(V))

endDate:gt(2014-07-31)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the string always going to look like that? Do you just want to split at `;` ?

Comment: For your example, `filter.split(";")` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    String filter = "startDate:gt(2014-07-31);(status:eq(A)||status:eq(V));endDate:gt(2014-07-31)";

    String str[]=filter.split(";");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else suggested use `String#split(";")` but if you really want to do it your way with the regular expressions to parse all the tokens and get specific information out use following:

```
String REGEX_MARKETOFFER_FILTER = "(\\()?([A-Za-z]*):([A-Za-z]*)(\\()([a-zA-Z0-9-,:]*)(\\))((\\|\\|)([A-Za-z]*):([A-Za-z]*)(\\()([a-zA-Z0-9-,:]*)(\\))(\\)))?(;)?";
```

Hope this helps.